# Function import when sp is changed

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0

I am using the function import feature of the entity framework to call a stored procedure from .net 4.0 code.

However, everytime I change the stored proc result set, I have to delete the function import and add it again.

Is there any way, in which I can incorporate the change by changing the code in the entity model, rather than having to delete and add the function import again?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using function import some changes are reflected automatically. For example if you add parameter to stored procedure and run *Update from database* it will automatically update both storage model definition and function import. If you modify result set which is not mapped to entity but to complex type instead you have to manually trigger function import updata - open function import and push Update button next to the complex type combo box.

Comment: must be a bug there somewhere, cause update button does nothing in my case.

Comment: @Entrodus - I'm experiencing the same behaviour in VS2010. Everything looks like it works but nothing is updated.

Comment: VS2017 it works. Hit ok and rememeber to save your edmx afterwards